# Find folders by variables and action on them

Tags: windows, powershell, variables, scripting, directory

I am trying to build a script with a variable based on a text file of folder names, find them in one directory and move them to a different directory (or delete them in an additional script).

For example:

```
$foldernames = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Folders.txt"
$startpath = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Test"
$topath = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Moved"
```

Then find each line item in folder names in the `$startpath` and if they are found move them to the `$topath`.

Comment: What keeps you from doing that? [Edit] your question and post your code. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will do the job. [*grin*] it *fakes* reading in your text file of to-move dirs [use Get-Content to do that for real], then gathers a list of dirs in the source location. next, it tests to see if the `.Name` is in the list of dirs to be moved. finally, it runs `Move-Item` to move the dir.

note the `-WhatIf` on the end ... remove that when you are ready to do your live test on your test data set. [*grin*]

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$ToMoveDirNameList = @(
    'test1'
    'TuTu'
    'GoGoGadget'
    'WPF'
    )

$SourceDir = $env:TEMP
$DestDir = 'd:\temp'

$SourceDirList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDir -Directory

foreach ($SDL_Item in $SourceDirList)
    {
    if ($SDL_Item.Name -in $ToMoveDirNameList)
        {
        Move-Item -LiteralPath $SDL_Item.FullName -Destination $DestDir -WhatIf
        }
    }
```

output ...

```
What if: Performing the operation "Move Directory" on target "Item: C:\Temp\test1 Destination: D:\temp\test1".
What if: Performing the operation "Move Directory" on target "Item: C:\Temp\TuTu Destination: D:\temp\TuTu".
What if: Performing the operation "Move Directory" on target "Item: C:\Temp\WPF Destination: D:\temp\WPF".
```

note #2 - there is NO error checking. this will give you lots of red error text if the destination already has a dir with the same name.

note #3 - there is no record of not-found dirs, either. [*grin*]

Comment: Thank you my good sir, you pointed me in the right direction and I was successful!

Comment: @RonaldWestII - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a little bit ... [*grin*]